# Discriminant of isogenous elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve with a rational $p$-torsion point $P$. Then $E$ is isogenous to the elliptic curve $E' := E/\langle P \rangle$ via the mod $P$ map. I know that the conductor of $E$ and $E'$ are the same, but the discriminant might not be. Is there are relation between $\Delta_{E}$ and $\Delta_{E'}$?

Comment: Other than the fact that they are both divisible by the conductor (and presumably satisfy Szpiro's conjecture), I think this is quite subtle. Even the case of conductor $30$ reveals complications....

Answer (score 4):

Section 2 in the preprint [Local invariants of isogenous elliptic curves](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.5519) by T. and V. Dokchitser might be what you are looking for. It states a result of Coates that if $p>3$ prime and $E \to E'$ is a $p$-isogeny (this is weaker than $E$ having a $p$-torsion point) then $\Delta_E^p/{\Delta_{E'}}$ is a $12$th power, and also the new result that if $p=2$ and $p=3$ then this ratio is a third and fourth power, respectively.